# dynamic taking up the spaces and make the widths equally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How could I show me expected result without modifying the HTML dom.

Both two pages will display the `page 1` layout. Though, on the HTML2 2, the `child2` has empty content.

What I expect is that the `HTML2` should display the page 2 layout.

Is it possible to achieve this by CSS only.
Thanks

## Expected result

[image: inline]

## HTML 1

```
    <div name="parent">
       <div name="child1">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
       <div name="child2">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
    </div>
```

## HTML 2

```
    <div name="parent">
       <div name="child1">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
       <div name="child2"></div>
    </div>
```

## CSS rules

```
    div[name="parent"] {
        display: flex;
        div {
            display: flex;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `flex-grow: 1`, and since `flex-basis` defaults to `auto`, the available space is shared equally after the sum of their content have been withdrawn, which simply means that even an empty flex item will take space, unless the content in `child1` is big enough to take it all, like in this sample:

```css
div[name="parent"] {
  display: flex;
}

div[name="parent"] div {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
Page 1
<div name="parent">
  <div name="child1">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
  <div name="child2">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
</div>

Page 2
<div name="parent">
  <div name="child1">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
  <div name="child2"></div>
</div>

<br><br>

Page 1
<div name="parent">
  <div name="child1">SOMETHING_INSIDE SOMETHING_INSIDE SOMETHING_INSIDE SOMETHING_INSIDE
  </div>
  <div name="child2">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
</div>

Page 2
<div name="parent">
  <div name="child1">SOMETHING_INSIDE SOMETHING_INSIDE SOMETHING_INSIDE SOMETHING_INSIDE
  </div>
  <div name="child2"></div>
</div>
```

---

In this case you can use the `:empty` selector and set the one that is empty to `display: none`

```css
div[name="parent"] {
  display: flex;
}

div[name="parent"] div {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div[name="parent"] div:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Page 1
<div name="parent">
  <div name="child1">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
  <div name="child2">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
</div>

<br> Page 2
<div name="parent">
  <div name="child1">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
  <div name="child2"></div>
</div>
```

---

If you also want to ensure, when both have content, that they always be equal wide (50%/50%), you set `flex-basis` to `0`

```css
div[name="parent"] {
  display: flex;
}

div[name="parent"] div {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.equal-width div {
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

```html
Page 1
<div name="parent">
  <div name="child1">SOMETHING_INSIDE SOMETHING_INSIDE SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
  <div name="child2">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
</div>

<br> Page 2
<div name="parent" class="equal-width">
  <div name="child1">SOMETHING_INSIDE SOMETHING_INSIDE SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
  <div name="child2">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question but I see no way of omitting a flex item based on  empty content. You could certainly do it with js and set the display to none:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myElement');
if (el.innerHTML === "")
   el.style.display = "none";
```

Once the flex item is not visible, the other flex item will grow to take all container space with `flex-grow:1`.

I have rearranged your code as it seems to have invalid css, and added a border so we can visualize the two flex items. Try manually setting `style="display:none"` on child2 to see child1 grow to full width.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click",   function(){
    toggleChild();
  });

  updateDivs();
};

toggleChild = function() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('child');
  if (divs[1].innerHTML == "") {
    divs[1].innerHTML = "SOMETHING_INSIDE";
    divs[1].style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    divs[1].innerHTML = "";
    divs[1].style.display = "none";
  }
}

updateDivs = function() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('child');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      if (divs[i].innerHTML == "") {
        divs[i].style.display = "none";
      }
  }
}
```

```css
div.parent {
  display:flex;
  width:100vw;
}     

div.parent div {
  flex-grow:1;
  border:1px solid black;
}

#toggle {
  margin:8px 0px 8px 0px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="toggle">Toggle child 2</div>

<div id="parent" class="parent">
  <div class="child" name="child1">SOMETHING_INSIDE</div>
  <div class="child" name="child2"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I added a toggle in the code snippet to visualize 1 or 2 column layout.